# Collectstatic populates thousands of files Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

So im trying to get my site to production and I have huge problems with the staticfiles(Im using white noise). Beside of my other Problems, each time when I run `./manage.py collectstatic` all files get compressed again and saved in the static folder. currently I have around 5500 static files.

[image]

```
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

Here is an example of the admin/css folder.

I have two questions:

1. How can I stop to populate so many files?
2. Is there a known way to clean the static folder so its not so heavy?

Comment: How many source files do you have in your `STATICFILES_DIRS`? And how many of them copying after the second consecutive `collectstatic` call?

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk I edited the question. I can't really answer the second question, since I don't know. Each time when I run "collectstatic" there are 1000 extra files in the folder. all compressed with .gz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> STATIC_ROOT - The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic
> will collect static files for deployment
>
> STATICFILES_DIRS - This
> setting defines the additional locations the staticfiles app will
> traverse if the FileSystemFinder finder is enabled, e.g. if you use
> the collectstatic or findstatic management command or use the static
> file serving view.

Make sure your `STATIC_ROOT` not included in `STATICFILES_DIRS` or you will double your files after each `collectstatic` call. Or maybe even lose source files if run it with `--clear` flag.

When you run `collectstatic` it shows statistics in the end:

```
0 static files copied to '/var/www/public/static', 825 unmodified, 135 post-processed.
```

Make sure you have `0` copied files after second run.

If your configuration is correct, you can use `--clear` flag. Before start collecting files, it will clear destination directory.

Comment: im still having some Problems but the folder is clear. Not really getting behind the STATICFILES_DIRS part but im getting there. Thanks anyway